# Rails how to make this view work? Devise, Enrolment system with courses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

How can I modify the **view** to make it work? I would like to have a "enroll now button" that will create a viewed_lessons record for the current_user?

```
class Course
    has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson
  #fields: course_id
  belongs_to :course
end
class User
  has_many :viewed_lessons
  has_many :viewed_courses
end
class ViewedLesson
  #fields: user_id, lesson_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end
class ViewedCourse
  #fields: user_id, course_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course  
end



class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end



def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    current_user.viewed_courses.create(course: @course)
  end  
end
```

One gotcha is that this would create a new viewed course every time they viewed the page, you would need some logic to only add each course once.

Perhaps something like this:

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  current_user.viewed_courses.create(course: @course) unless ViewedCourse.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: @course.id)
end
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model, you can [validate for uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)...

**viewed_course.rb**

```
class ViewedCourse
  ...
  validates :course, uniqueness: { scope: :user, message: "should happen once per user" }
  ...
end
```

It doesn't look like you're using ViewedCourses in your show template. If you do later, you might want to try [the find_or_create_by method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) in some instances.

One final piece of unsolicited feedback, your verbiage seems a little confusing to me. "Enroll" and "Show" feel like two very different actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The big issue that I have is that I cant make the view work. In the first part of my question: How can I modify the view to make it work? I would like to have a "enrol now" button that will create a viewed_lessons record for the current_user? Thank you in advance